# rake db:seed yields syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, syntax-error, rake

When I enter rake db:seed in terminal, I receive:

> SyntaxError:
> /Users/-/src/-/db/seeds.rb:17: syntax
> error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:seed

...where db/seeds.rb has:

```
Category.create(kind: 'Food/Drink')        #line 9, everything above is commented out
Category.create(kind: 'Entertainment') 
Category.create(kind: 'Organization')
Category.create(kind: 'Business')
Category.create(kind: 'Collegiate')

Location.create(area: 'Downtown NB') 
Location.create(area: 'College Ave', 
Location.create(area: 'Cook/Douglass')     #line 17
Location.create(area: 'Livingston') 
Location.create(area: 'Busch') 
Location.create(area: 'Surrounding NB')
Location.create(area: 'Out of Town')
```

A --trace shows:

> rake db:seed --trace
>
> ** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
>
> ** Execute db:seed
>
> ** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
>
> ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>
> ** Execute environment
>
> ** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
>
> rake aborted!
>
> SyntaxError: /Users/EuphoriaComplex/src/venture/venture/db/seeds.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo on line 16th:

```
Location.create(area: 'College Ave',
```

should be

```
Location.create(area: 'College Ave')
```